# Query is creating one record for every image attached to a row in for each loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which pulls a list of rides attached to a particular theme park and shows their details and any attached photos (the photos are pulled from a separate table and connected by 'ride_id'). Below is the query

```
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query2="SELECT * FROM  `tpf_rides` LEFT JOIN tpf_images
ON tpf_rides.ride_id=tpf_images.ride_id 
WHERE tpf_rides.park_id = $park_id AND `type` LIKE '%Roller Coaster%' ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result2 = $pdo->query($query2);
```

The problem is when I list the results pulled from this query it creates duplicate rows for a ride, one for each image.

What is want is:

```
Ride 1 - Type <br>  
Manufactured by xxx, Opened xxxx <br>
image1 image2 

Ride 2 - Type <br>  
Manufactured by xxx, Opened xxxx <br>
image1 image2 image3
```

but what I currently have is

```
Ride 1 - Type <br>  
    Manufactured by xxx, Opened xxxx <br>
    image1 

Ride 1 - Type <br>  
    Manufactured by xxx, Opened xxxx <br>
    image2 

Ride 2 - Type <br>  
    Manufactured by xxx, Opened xxxx <br>
    image1
```

Below is the for each loop I'm using. What would I need to alter on the query or loop to have this work correctly?

```
<?php foreach ($result2 as $row2): ?>

<h2 style="display:inline;"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></h2><h3 style="display:inline;"> - <?php echo $row2['type']; ?></h3> 
<h3>Manufactured by <?php echo $row2['make']; ?>, Opened <?php echo $row2['opened']; ?> </h3>
<img border="0" src="<?php echo $row2['url']; ?>" style="max-height:250px; max-width:250px;" >

<br>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm still at the early stages of understanding PHP and MySQL so a detailed answer would really help. Thank you.

Comment: To isolate the issue, try firing the SQL directly from MySQL workbench and see what you get. If you are happy with what you see, the problem lies in the PHP code. Else you got to fix your query. Ofcourse, this is not the answer you want but this is how I debug my issues when dealing with frontends and DBs. You'll answer your own question then.

Comment: It looks like its the query, if I run it through phpmyadmin it creates multiply rows of the same ride, one for each image associated with it. I then tried grouping the results by 'name' but this caused only one image per ride to show up. Where is the inbetween?! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this now with help from elsewhere. If it helps anyone else this is the code to make it happen:

```
$sLastRide = '';
foreach ($result2 AS $row)
{
    $sRide = $row['name'] . $row['type'];
    if (strcasecmp($sRide, $sLastRide) != 0)
    {
        if (!empty($sLastRide))
        {
            print('</div>' . PHP_EOL);
        }
        $sLastRide = $sRide;
        print('<div>' . PHP_EOL);
        printf('<h2 style="display:inline;">%s</h2><h3 style="display:inline;"> - %s</h3>' . PHP_EOL, $row['name'], $row['type']);
        printf('<h3>Manufactured by %s, Opened %s</h3>' . PHP_EOL, $row['make'], $row['opened']);
    }
    printf('<img src="%s" style="max-height: 250px; max-width: 250px" alt=""/>' . PHP_EOL, $row['url']);
}
print('</div>');
```